# Swift Share Extension crashes for Google News sharing

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a Swift share extension that accepts URLs and text items (code below). It works as expected for many apps (Mail, Safari, NetNewsWire etc.).

When I try to share content from within Google News the extension crashes. The view doesn't fully render, only the semi-transparent background shows up. It stays stuck in that state and I have to kill Google News to be able to use it again.

I have tried adding `Logger` statements, which don't show up anywhere. I have tried debugging the extension running on my physical device using XCode unsuccessfully. Sadly, I can't install Google News on the iOS simulator.

The extension prints a single error, even in the success case (e.g. sharing from Safari):

```
-[_EXSinkLoadOperator loadItemForTypeIdentifier:completionHandler:expectedValueClass:options:] nil expectedValueClass allowing {(
    _EXItemProviderSandboxedResource,
    NSData,
    ...
)}
```

Here's my view controller:

```
//...

class ShareViewController: UIViewController {    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard
            let extensionItem = extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem,
            let itemProvider = extensionItem.attachments?.first
        else {
            self.close()
            return
        }
        
        if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(UTType.url.identifier) {
            itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.url.identifier, options: nil) { urlCoded, error in
                if let error {
                    self.close()
                    return
                }
                
                if let url = urlCoded as? URL {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.renderView(url)
                    }
                } else {
                    self.close()
                    return
                }
            }
        } else if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(UTType.text.identifier) {
            itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.text.identifier, options: nil) { providedText, error in
                if let error {
                    self.close()
                    return
                }
                
                guard
                    let text = providedText as? String,
                    let url = self.extractURL(text)
                else {
                    self.close()
                    return
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.renderView(url)
                }
            }
        } else {
            self.close()
            return
        }
    }
    
    private func renderView(_ url: URL) {
        self.saveLink(url: url)
        
        // host the SwiftU view
        let contentView = UIHostingController(rootView: ShareView(url: url))
        self.addChild(contentView)
        self.view.addSubview(contentView.view)
        contentView.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        // set up constraints
        contentView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false, block: { _ in self.close() })
    }
    
    private func saveLink(url: URL) {
        // writes to a .plist file that's shared with the main app
    }
    
    private func close() {
        self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
    private func extractURL(_ text: String) -> URL? {
        do {
            let detector = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
            let matches = detector.matches(
                in: text,
                options: [],
                range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count)
            )
            
            if let firstMatch = matches.first, let range = Range(firstMatch.range, in: text) {
                let url = String(text[range])
                return URL(string: url)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Unable to extract URL from text: \(error)")
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}
```

Not sharing the view code, it's a simple SwiftUI view that shows `sheet` and then disappears again. Here's are the activation rules for the extension:

```
<key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
```

The issue is on iOS 17.2 and upwards.